# pkill with regex

Tags: process, regular-expression, kill

I have few java processes running like below,

`java -jar /my/path/to/app/myapp.jar`

`java -jar /my/path/to/app/prodapp.jar`

`java -jar /my/path/to/app/testapp.jar`

`java -jar /my/path/to/app/myapp_v.01.jar`

Now I can kill a particular process by `pkill -f myapp.jar` which is working as expected.
how do I kill myapp_v.01.jar using a regex, I tried `pkill -f  myapp_*.jar`. 
What is wrong with this regex ?

I am not looking for an alternative for `pkill`, I wanted to know why is the regex not working.

Comment: What's the point of using a regex? If you want to kill `myapp_v.01.jar`, just kill `myapp_v.01.jar`. Using a regex only introduces the risk of matching something unwanted, with no added value at all.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to understand the basics of regular expressions for this. The `*` modifier does not mean 'anything' as it is often assumed. The asterisk has this meaning in the shell but that's something different, not a regex. `*` means: take the previous character (or group of characters if preceeded by a `[]` group) and try to match it between zero and unlimited number of occurrences.

So what you're actually checking with `myapp_*.jar` is whether any of the following are present in the process list:

```
myapp.jar
myapp_.jar
myapp__.jar
myapp___.jar
...
```

See what I mean? It does not match 'myapp_v.01.jar' in any way. If you want to match any character, you're going to need `.`. So your regex for `pkill` could be: `myapp_*.*.jar`